# Iframe inside a DIV incompatibility Chrome-Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, google-chrome, incompatibility

If you put an *iframe* inside a *div*:

```
<div id="big-box">
    <iframe src="http://www.google.com" class="frame">
    </iframe>
</div>
```

And use CSS to ask the iframe to occupy all the available screen area:

```
#big-box {
    background-color: #aaf;
}

.frame {
    border: medium none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

It works perfect on Chrome (12.07) but it fails on Firefox (3.6.17). [This demo](http://jsfiddle.net/navi2000/4wevP/1/) shows that in Chrome the entire JSFiddle area contains the *iframe*, but if you try this sample in Firefox the *iframe* will occupy all width, but not all height.

Note also that if you fix width and height for *big-box* it works, but this is not the point (I can't change this). The point is why this incompatibility and how to fix it (do always as Chrome does).

Comment: It appears that it's not working on Chrome 16, this was possibly a bug with chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The latest version of Google Chrome (14.0.835) displays the fiddle in the exact same way as the latest version of Firefox (3.6.23) and the latest version of IE (9.0.3). So you can see that Google Chrome shouldn't have done it "right" in the first place. It was displaying what you wanted by mistake...

Adding `position: absolute;` to the style of `.frame` will achieve what you're going for. It  works on all three mentioned browsers.

Here's the fiddle: [jsfiddle.net/Q5mt5/1](http://jsfiddle.net/Q5mt5/1)

Comment: you have "normalise css" on your jsFiddle. This won't help show browser differences.

Comment: @JamesKhoury: Thanks for the tip. I've never used fiddles. I just provided one since the OP asked for it.

Comment: What kind of firefox version is "2.6.23"? the latest one is 10.0a1

Comment: I meant 3.6.23. It's not the newest version after all. I only use Firefox for testing. My standard browser is Chrome...

Answer (score 1):

taking from [Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7706096/iframe-inside-a-div-incompatibility-chrome-firefox/7749158#7749158)' jsFiddle I figured you can do:

```
html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding:0px;
}
div {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

iframe {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4HuY/3/) works in Firefox 4 and Chrome 14 *(sorry thats all I have here with me atm.)*

Answer (score 0):

Firefox is correct here. An `iframe` is an inline replaced element by default, so it sits on the baseline. If you add `display: block;` to the style for the frame class, then it will obey block sizing rules and completely cover the `div`.

Comment: I've tried to add `display:block`, but still not working. There is no changes :(